# How much more unclear is Full HD (1920x1080) on a 17-inch LCD than a 15-inch?

Tags: laptop, resolution

Recipient of a gift card for Lenovo, my aunt desires the Lenovo Y700:

1. either the [15" version](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/y700-series/y700-15-inch/) which offers both Full HD (1920 x 1080) and Ultra HD (3840 x 2160)
2. or the [17"](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/y700-series/y700-17-inch/)  which offers only Full HD (1920 x 1080); strangely, Ultra HD is NOT offered though this has bigger screen.

   She presently uses, and has no problems with, a 15" laptop with Full HD (1920 x 1080). Now she prefers a bigger screen, but she does not know how a 17" appears with only Full HD (1920 x 1080) and so fears blurriness or fuzziness.

Comment: This is an opinion based question... but the reality is if Full HD is not blurry on a 27" or even a 50" display, it won't be on a 17" either.

Comment: I recommend to all laptop buyers, to go to a store and lay fingers on it first (regardless of whether you plan to purchase online). kinesthetics and ergonomics are essential.

Comment: @acejavelin - Opinion-based it may be, but to claim 1080p is going to be crisp on a 50" monitor is somewhat misleading. You'd need to be better than 8 ft away before the pixels weren't individually discernible, vs 1ft  for a 15" screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin Perhaps... but I can tell you I have 2 Acer 27" monitors in front of me less than 2' away, both with Full HD resolution, and there is no pixelation or fuzziness, and my eyesight is pretty good. A 17" screen of reasonable quality will not suffer from any of your concerns at that resolution, especially since the majority of 17" displays are 1600x900 resolution and there is no outcry of poor quality display. The opinion based reference I referred to deals with the fact that those type of questions, where answers are opinion based and not factual, are off-topic on SU.

Comment: I have 2 27" 1440p screens in front of me. They are lovely even at <1ft. I wouldn't dream of using a 27" at only 1080p, it would be far too fuzzy to be pleasant. I also have a 50" 1080p TV which is fabulous for watching movies on, but makes a lousy computer monitor from less than 6ft. Comparatively, it has pixels like dinner-plates. For the OP, I doubt the difference from 15 to 17 would be too noticeable, we're discussing extremes - my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, how clear something appears in the laptop screen is going to vary more from manufacturer to manufacturer, as well as what settings you use in Windows, and even on your own eyesight.

However, speaking in general terms, a 17" screen is not going to be any less clear than a 15" screen if they both have the same pixel count.  If your aunt has exceptional eyesight, she may be able to better discern individual pixels on the 17" owing to their larger size.  They will not be blurry, but again with good eyes, they might appear a little more jagged.

Windows settings for zoom will play a factor here.  At the same pixel count, the 17" screen objects will be physically larger, so they may be better seen at their normal size.  On a 15" screen, you may want the items to appear bigger, so Windows may have suggested (or even defaulted to) a larger zoom level.  In certain applications, this can cause text or images to appear blurry.

Comparing the two 15" displays with different resolutions is different altogether.  The Ultra HD is going to appear crisper because it can approximate curves a lot more closely than the regular HD, especially in high contrast situations (i.e., black text on a white background).  In practice, though, most applications will have little noticeable difference to most people.